# how to achieve textInput delegate in QML ListView

Tags: qt, qml

how can I achieve the result that can edit an item's text when I doubleClick ListView's item, just similar to the spinBox delegate used in ListView:

[image]

Comment: See how to customize a SpinBox [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-spinbox). You'll probably just need to toggle the `editable` property on the double-click.

Answer (score -1):

```
TextInput{
  id:textInput
  enabled:false
  onEditingFinished: enabled=false
}
MouseArea{
  //anchor mousearea to textInput size
  onDoubleClicked() : textInput.enabled=true
}
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding explanatory text, and maybe showing the code within the context of a ListView delegate. Also, the OP is asking about using a SpinBox, not a TextInput.

Comment: sorry! I have no got the example picture so put SpinBox's, actully, I want to achieve double click then modify item's text, not number.